# I can't wrap my head around the logic of using for loop 5 times for bubble sort

Tags: c++, algorithm, bubble-sort

What is the more efficient way of doing the bubble sort instead of me copying and pasting the for loop 5 times using the code given?

My logic here is to check if array[1] (9) is bigger than array[2] (6), since it is bigger it will swap the elements. But once it reaches the end of the array I have to copy and paste the for loop so the bubble sort algorithm will start over again checking the array.

I did not use variables, rather dynamic allocations because it is easier for me to understand.

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int array[] = { 9, 6, 2, 8, 3, 1, 7, 5, 4 };

    int temp;

    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    {
        if (array[i] > array[i + 1])
        {
            temp = array[i];
            array[i] = array[i + 1];
            array[i + 1] = temp;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    {
        if (array[i] > array[i + 1])
        {
            temp = array[i];
            array[i] = array[i + 1];
            array[i + 1] = temp;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    {
        if (array[i] > array[i + 1])
        {
            temp = array[i];
            array[i] = array[i + 1];
            array[i + 1] = temp;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    {
        if (array[i] > array[i + 1])
        {
            temp = array[i];
            array[i] = array[i + 1];
            array[i + 1] = temp;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    {
        if (array[i] > array[i + 1])
        {
            temp = array[i];
            array[i] = array[i + 1];
            array[i + 1] = temp;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    {
        std::cout << array[i] << std::endl;
    }

}
```

Comment: On bubble sort, you repeat until done.

Comment: Maybe you could use a loop?

Answer (score 2):

You seem to already know that you can repeat something by using a loop. If you want to repeat a loop, just put it in a loop:

```
for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++)
  for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    {
        if (array[i] > array[i + 1])
        {
            temp = array[i];
            array[i] = array[i + 1];
            array[i + 1] = temp;
        }
    }
```

I'm not clear why you would want to do this just 5 times though, there's nothing special about 5.

Also, note that this is not the most efficient way to write a bubble sort (e.g. you don't need to check elements that have already been bubbled up).

Comment: When I do it 5 times, the whole array gets sorted, anything less than 5 it wont be sorted properly from lowest to biggest

Comment: Maybe, but there are inputs that will not work even with 5 iterations. Try a vector that is in descending order.

Comment: I see. So then what would be the optimum way to do it?

Comment: Just search for `bubble sort` online. There are many resources available for this, and any good textbook will have this information as well.